# Aggregate Functions for different groups

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

Consider a table 'Collections' with columns

```
region | name | amount 
R1       Ron    100
R1       Ron    200
R1       John   200
R1       John   300
R2       Ron    100
R2       Ron    100
R2       Ron    100
R2       John   100
```

Output:

```
region |Region Total| Region Count | name | Total| Count
R1              800              4    Ron     300      2
R1              800              4   John     500      2
R2              400              4    Ron     300      3
R2              400              4   John     100      1
```

what i need to do is calculate the sum of amount by region and then by name
and also the count of collections by region and then by name

so the query goes this way

```
select region, (Select sum(amount) from Collections A where A.region = B.region) as 'Region Total', 
(Select count(amount) from Collections A where A.region = B.region) 'Region Count',
 name,
sum(amount) as 'amount' , 
count 
from Collections B 
group by region, name
```

Question : How can i do this without using those Subqueries

Comment: @MahmoudGamal +1 on your comment.

Comment: and +1 on yours - now I remember why we don't do this

Comment: First of all, you need a PRIMARY KEY

Comment: In reality there are three table from where this values are coming and they have primary keys which i think might not be relevant to explain the scenario

Comment: So, in reality the problem is nothing like the situation described !?!?!

Comment: @Strawberry I took away the irrelevant part , the question completely specifies what i need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too simple? (seems like that I'm wrong)

```
SELECT region, name, SUM(amount), COUNT(*)
FROM tab
GROUP BY region, name;
```

### UPDATED

I think following query has all information what you need. Now, it's time to convert display format in client side.

```
SELECT region, name, SUM(amount), COUNT(*)
FROM tab
GROUP BY region, name

UNION ALL

SELECT region, NULL, SUM(amount), COUNT(*)
FROM tab
GROUP BY region

+--------+------+-------------+----------+
| region | name | SUM(amount) | COUNT(*) |
+--------+------+-------------+----------+
| R1     | John |         500 |        2 |
| R1     | Ron  |         300 |        2 |
| R2     | John |         100 |        1 |
| R2     | Ron  |         300 |        3 |
| R1     | NULL |         800 |        4 |
| R2     | NULL |         400 |        4 |
+--------+------+-------------+----------+
```

### UPDATE 2

```
SELECT x.region, y.s2, y.c2, x.name, x.s1, x.c1
FROM
(
    SELECT region, name, SUM(amount) s1, COUNT(*) c1
    FROM tab
    GROUP BY region, name
) x INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT region,  SUM(amount) s2, COUNT(*) c2
    FROM tab
    GROUP BY region
) y ON x.region = y.region
+--------+------+----+------+------+----+
| region | s2   | c2 | name | s1   | c1 |
+--------+------+----+------+------+----+
| R1     |  800 |  4 | John |  500 |  2 |
| R1     |  800 |  4 | Ron  |  300 |  2 |
| R2     |  400 |  4 | John |  100 |  1 |
| R2     |  400 |  4 | Ron  |  300 |  3 |
+--------+------+----+------+------+----+
```

If your real query is very complex or there are a lot of rows, I think `UNION` or `WITH ROLLUP` is better for you even though query output format is not same with display format.

Comment: @InoS Heo yes you are wrong my friend , I need sum of amount and count for Sub group name

Comment: @user2670177 aha. wait a minute.

Comment: I should not have NULL values

Comment: @user2670177 then wait a minute. I'll try inline view and join

Comment: with my subqueries it takes 12 seconds for just 5000 records, ill try your answers and see if they scale better

Comment: Thanks @InoS Heo , it is fast